# Resize Shiny renderImage for mobile

Tags: css, r, shiny

I have a Shiny App on my own Shiny Server that displays png images on a web page. This works fine. However, the images are too wide when the page is viewed on an iPhone. In my case, the correct size for the png image on a large screen is 600w x 400h and for an iPhone 330w x 220h works well. How do I auto-resize the image?

```
R Script
library("shiny")
library("tidyverse")

ui <- fluidPage(
  imageOutput("img")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$img <- renderImage({
    
  path_to_png <- "/var/www/..."
    
  list(src = path_to_png,
       width = "600",
       height = "400",
       alt = "Chart of good stuff")
    
  }, deleteFile = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either use relative units and/or add breakpoints in custom CSS. It looks like `imageOutput` puts a div around the image so you could do:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  imageOutput("img", width = "40vw", height = "30vh")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$img <- renderImage({
    
  path_to_png <- "/var/www/..."
    
  list(src = path_to_png,
       width = "100%",
       height = "100%",
       alt = "Chart of good stuff")
    
  }, deleteFile = FALSE)
}
```

OR using CSS + breakpoints, something like:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
     tags$head(
      tags$style(
        "@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        #img {
          width: 330px !important;
          height: 220px !important;
        }
        }"
      )
    ),
   imageOutput("img")
)
...
```

Comment: Trying option one (viewport units) with, width = "84vw", height = "44vh" the png is good on desktop, very distorted on iPhone. If I delete ' height = "100%",' the desktop remains good and the iPhone img is no longer distorted except there is too much empty white space below the image. How do I keep the images looking like this without the excess white space on the iPhone?

Comment: It helps to know a little HTML/CSS to get the sizing right (see e.g. https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_images.asp). The code: imageOutput("x", width = "w1", height = "h2") along with the code in renderImage: width="w2" and height="h2" generates the HTML `<div id="x" width="w1" height="h1"> <img href="..." width="w2" height="h2"> </div>`. To keep the aspect ratio you can use width=100%, height="auto". To remove whitespace, make the height smaller in imageOutput.